# Set Default Transparent Pixels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity, nodata

Is there a way to set QGIS to automatically load in images with no data values of (0,0,0) as transparent instead of black? I've looked through the forums, tried saving a .qml file out, looked through all the settings, and I can't find a way to do it. We process thousands of images, and we need to be able to look at them without black no-data areas covering up the images underneath. I can manually set it by going in to the properties of a raster layer, putting 0 in as a no data value and hitting apply, but I need a way to do this automatically when the images load in. In ERDAS Imagine or ArcGIS this is an easy thing to set. Can it be done in QGIS?